# Include path with constant and variable

Tags: php, include

I'm trying to include a file to current php page but the name of the file depens on the lang.

This line does not work:

```
include_once PATH.'lang/'.$_SESSION['lang'].'.php';
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What error did you receive and what's `PATH`?

Comment: Where does `PATH` come from ?

Comment: @luweiqi I'm not receiving an error, the file is not included. I have an array in that file included. Trying to load the array on the parent page does not work.

Comment: When you ask a question about an error, ***ALWAYS***  post the error log. To enable error reporting to your php code append `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your script, what does it return ?

Comment: PATH is a constant defined in another file. If I assign this: PATH.'lang/'.$_SESSION['lang'].'.php' , to a variable and then a show it, here's the result: http://localhost/123/456/lang/es_ES.php

Comment: And you have a directory called `localhost`???

Comment: @PedroLobito I never talked about and **ERROR** if you are assuming there's an **ERROR** it's not my fault, also I have error reporting on when I'm writing some lines ;-)

Comment: if you "***never talked about and ERROR***", everything should be ok and you don't need help. Voting close based on "***unclear what you're asking***". Your attitude isn't helping you.

Comment: Thank you luweiqi && AbraCadaver for your help, and special thanks to João for resolve my clear question ^_^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem should be the "PATH". It must be a string to concatenate with the other strings. For example:

```
include_once '/sites/all/files/'.'lang/'.$_SESSION['lang'].'.php';
```

Also be careful with the slashes that make your path to the file.